Is it possible to conveniently get the command content generated by `shell()` in Snakemake?
Snakemake version
❯ snakemake --version
8.20.6

Code
cmd = (
    "(fastp --thread {snakemake.threads} "
    "{extra} "
    "{adapters} "
    "{reads} "
    "{trimmed} "
    "{json} "
    "{html} ) {log}"
)
shell(cmd)

Above is a code snippet from snakemake-wrappersbiofastpwrapper.py at release-v4.6.1 · snakemakesnakemake-wrappers.
What I want
I want to get the instantiated content of cmd, cmd.format(...) can work, but it's too cumbersome.
Since shell() can execute it, it must can also fill the placeholder, so I have read the source code of shell.py, but it seems there is not a function or variable to get the instantiated content?
Does anyone know how to get the instantiated  content of cmd conveniently?

Have you tried cmd.format(**locals()) ? It works for me.

@bli Thank you for your response! It works! I later found out that the real problem was :q in the " {snakemake.input[0]:q}" (source code: fastqc wrapper). It seems :q will safely quote the variable, maybe removing it doesn't affect the program in general? Then I can simply use f"" or f"""...""". Your answer gave me a new idea, thank you.
